# Facebook user search not finding friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I am using facebook [search api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0#search) to search for my friends, but it only works on small group of them.

Are there any restrictions here? And is there any work around?

```
/search?q={my friend}&type=user
```

- I also include user access token.

Comment: Users can specify in their settings whether they want to be found via search or not.

Comment: @CBroe since we are talking about my friend on Facebook, that I got access to via taggable friends api and game inevitable fiends api. It only make sense to me that an app will have access to user friends via public search api. Is there any work around that you familiar with, beside the two apis I just mentioned?

Comment: Graph API Search functionality is rudimentary at best. Why do you need to search for friends within your app anyway? (If you want to let your users invite their friends, then go check the app development FAQ in the FB docs, it lists they ways in which that is possible.)